# How to create object from arrays of row in laravel Elequent

Tags: mysql, laravel

Here I want to make the array inside "property" to an object where the key of the object will be the value of 'key_name' column of product_property table

```
[{
    "sort_order": 1,
    "name": "Samosas",
    "visible": 1,
    "description": null,
    "property": [
        {
            "product_uuid": "95be9cf4-7121-492b-8725-762e6353ac51",
            "key_name": "categories",
            "key_value": "Starter"
        },
        {
            "product_uuid": "95be9cf4-7121-492b-8725-762e6353ac51",
            "key_name": "print_order",
            "key_value": "1"
        }

    ]
}]
```

This is what I want

```
[{
    "sort_order": 1,
    "name": "Samosas",
    "visible": 1,
    "description": null,
    "property": {
        "categories": "Starter",
        "print_order": "1"
    }
}]
```

I tried with Product::with('property')->get() and it results the first array.
Is there any Eloquent way to do that or raw sql or Query Builder?
Looping throw the result and make that object is possible but here i want something from SQL end

```
$products = Product::with('property')->get();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $array = [];
    foreach ($product->property as $property) {
        $array[$property['key_name']] = $property['key_value'];
    }
    $product->properties = $array;
}
```

This looping giving me the results but its from php end

```
public function property(){
    return $this->hasMany(ProductProperty::class, 'product_uuid', 'uuid');
}
```

The Product model

```
Product table
"sort_order",
"name",
"visible",
"description",

Product Property table
"product_uuid",
"key_name",
"key_value"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `hasOne()` in `property` function inside the `Product` model to achieve that.

Comment: What you have done so far? Can you share your controller code?

Comment: @Shrey Thanks for your suggestion but it doesnot help here

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Product::with('property')->get();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $array = [];
    foreach ($product->property as $property) {
        $array[$property['key_name']] = $property['key_value'];
    }
    $product->properties = (object) $array;
}
```

Add object. It will convert this to a std object.